# Mail Reader Sampler - Unable to read mail from yopmail/mailinator using jmeter

Tags: email, jmeter, pop3

Mail Reader Sampler - Unable to read mail from  yopmail/mailinator using jmeter

I am sending mail to abc123@yopmail.com , i want to read that mail or check whether received the mail in abc123@yopmail.com or not.
I haven't got any POP3/IMAP details of yopmail/mailinator.

Any other way i can verify the received emails.

Response in Jmeter - Error code -500

Imap cred for yopmail:

```
mail-imap.yopmail.com
port - not mentioned
username - abc@yopmail.com
password - not mentioned
```